# Zeta-urn model simulation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, computational-physics, software, statistics

In the Zeta-urn model, given $M$ urns and $N$ balls, the probability distribution at equilibrium is:
\begin{equation}
P(n_i)=Z^{-1}(N,M,\beta)e^{-\beta\sum_{i}E_i},
\end{equation}
with $E_i=\ln(n_i+1)$, $\beta$ a real parameter and $Z$ a normalization constant.

Now, does anyone know a simple way to implement a simulation of this system in order to obtain the distribution of balls at equilibrium, given $\beta$ and $\rho$?

The question is about the dynamic of the system, i.e. how to define a rule to fill the urns in order to reach an equilibrium state that satisfy the probability distribution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic e.g. because it seems to be about statistics & software implementation rather than physics. Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Szabolcs: You are encouraged to improve the post via edits if possible. It still seems to ask for software implementation, though.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, sorry, I deleted my comment before you responded because I realized it was pointless. I am not arguing for reopening.